# Rick and Morty questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Once the second season starts, and we have more than 11 episodes to discuss, will Rick and Morty questions be on topic here?

For those who don't know, Rick and Morty is a cartoon on Adult Swim, and the premise is that an eccentric genius and his relatively dull grandson go on adventures to other dimensions and galaxies together.  The show grew out of a web cartoon, which was extremely risqué, called "Doc and Mharti", a very crude spoof of *Back to the Future*.

While the show is primarily a comedy, there is a strong undertone of science fiction and fantasy.

Would it be a better fit for the Movies & TV SE, or for our beloved SF&F SE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overview on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rick_and_Morty) suggests that it's very strongly on topic:

> Rick and Morty is an American adult animated television series created
>   by Justin Roiland and Dan Harmon for Adult Swim. The series follows
>   the misadventures of alcoholic scientist Rick and his easily
>   influenced grandson Morty, who **split their time between domestic
>   family life and interdimensional travel.**

as does the blurb on [Adult Swim](http://www.adultswim.com/videos/rick-and-morty/):

> Every episode of Rick and Morty is now on AdultSwim.com for free. **Rick
>   is a mad scientist who drags his grandson, Morty, on crazy sci-fi
>   adventures**

Comment: I forgot to mention the alcoholism.  It is surprisingly important to the show.  Also, Rick burps in the middle of almost every sentence he speaks.

Comment: @wadcheber that changes nothing...

Comment: @Pureferret - I never said it did.  Just commenting on Richard's answer